# Calling an action once a view (window) that was made programmatically is touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow

I'm currently creating a drop-down search bar inside my app.
When the drop down animation begins a new `-UIView` overlays the current one to create the black transparent effect.

However I need to know how I can create a listener that sends an action once my `-UIView` is touched.

This is how I created the transparent `-UIView` / `-UIWindow`

```
    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 0, 0, 320, 750)];
    blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [window addSubview:blackView];
    blackView.alpha = 0.6;
```

Image of the drop-down and the `-UIView`.

[image: App Image]

Comment: have you heard about UITapGestureRecognizer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your view such like,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(TouchViewMethod:)];
gestureRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
gestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.yourViewName addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];
```

Method

```
-(void)TouchViewMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)touch
{

   //// Do your stuff;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

or you have to add the tapgetsture recognizer to the view.